# Checkers Java Code Error

Tags: java, eclipse, mouselistener, jagged-arrays, mouse-listeners

I have created two classes for checkers game. One is board and the other is pieces. The difficulty that I am having is that with the pieces I cannot seem to get them to move and neither can I get them to stay in that spot correctly and that I am actually unable to go any further due to the fact that I do not understand what is going wrong here. Can someone please correct me on what I am doing wrong.

```
            import java.awt.Color;
            import java.awt.Dimension;
            import java.awt.Graphics;
            import java.awt.GridLayout;
            import java.awt.Image;

            import javax.swing.JButton;
            import javax.swing.JPanel;


            public class Board extends JPanel {

              private int[][] state;
              public final static int EMPTY = 0;
              public final static int RED = 1;
              public final static int BLUE = 2;
              public final static int BLUE_KING = 3;
              public final static int RED_KING = 4;
              public final static int HIGHLIGHT = 5;

              public Board() {
                state = new int[8][8];
                setSize(400, 400);
              }

              public void paint(Graphics g){

                for(int y=0;y<8;y++){
                  for(int x=0;x<8;x++){
                    if(x%2 == y%2){
                       g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    else{
                       g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

                    }
                    g.fillRect(x*50,y*50,50,50);

                    switch(state[x][y]){
                    //6 cases that will be available for this game
                    /*
                     * Empty will be the empty spot; Red will be the red checkers. Blue will be the blue checkers. The blue king will occur when it reaches other side
                     * and the red king will occur when it reaches other side. The highlight will show the possible moves that can occur when it [red/blue] king will be selected
                     * 
                     */
                      case EMPTY: break;
                      case RED: 
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fillOval(x*50,y*50,50,50);
                        break;
                      case BLUE:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillOval(x*50,y*50,50,50);
                        break;
                      case BLUE_KING:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillOval(x*50,y*50,50,50);
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.drawString("K",x*50+25,y*50+25);
                        break;
                      case RED_KING:
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fillOval(x*50,y*50,45,45);
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.drawString("K",x*50+25,y*50+25);
                        break;
                      case HIGHLIGHT:
                        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        g.drawOval(x*50,y*50,50,50);
                        break;
                    }

                  }
                }
              }

              public void setState(int x,int y, int s){
                state[x][y]=s;
              }

              public int getState(int x,int y){
                return state[x][y];
              }



            }
```

Also here's the pieces class

```
                        import javax.swing.*;
                        import java.awt.*;
                        import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
                        import java.awt.event.*;

                        public class Checkers implements MouseListener
                        {
                           int p1pieces = 12; 
                           int p2pieces = 12;
                           int xcord;
                           int ycord;
                           int exist;
                           int exist2;
                           int leftx = 0;
                           int lefty = 1;
                           int rightx = 0;
                           int righty = 1;
                           int oldXvalue, oldYvalue;
                           Board b=new Board();
                           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers");
                           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                           JButton newgame = new JButton("New Game");
                           JTextField turn = new JTextField("Players one turn");
                           JTextField pieces = new JTextField("Player 1 has " +p1pieces + " pieces. Player 2 has " + p2pieces + " pieces.");


                           public Checkers()
                           {
                             frame.setSize(500,500);
                             frame.add(b);
                             frame.add(panel);
                             frame.setVisible(true);
                             frame.addMouseListener(this);
                             b.setState(0,0, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(2,0, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(4,0, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(6,0, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(7,1, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(5,1, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(3,1, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(1,1, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(0,2, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(2,2, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(4,2, Board.BLUE);
                             b.setState(6,2, Board.BLUE);

                             b.setState(7,7, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(5,7, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(3,7, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(1,7, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(0,6, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(2,6, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(4,6, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(6,6, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(1,5, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(3,5, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(5,5, Board.RED);
                             b.setState(7,5, Board.RED);
                           }


                           public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
                           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
                           public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
                           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

                          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                          {
                           Object o = e.getSource(); 
                           {
                                 oldXvalue = xcord;
                                 oldYvalue = ycord;
                               }
                           xcord = (e.getX() / 50);
                           ycord = (e.getY() / 50) ;
                           exist = b.getState(xcord,ycord);
                           if(exist == 1 || exist == 2)

                           highlightleft();
                           highlightright();
                           move();

                           b.repaint();
                          }

                          public void highlightleft()
                           {
                             exist = b.getState(xcord, ycord);
                             if(exist == 1)
                             {
                               exist2 = b.getState(xcord-1, ycord -1);
                             }
                             if(exist == 2)
                             {
                               exist2 = b.getState(xcord-1, ycord +1);

                             }
                             if(exist == 1 && exist2 == 0)
                             {
                                b.setState(xcord-1,ycord -1, Board.HIGHLIGHT);
                               leftx = xcord -1;
                               lefty = ycord -1;

                             }
                             else if(exist == 2 && exist2 == 0)
                             {
                               b.setState(xcord -1, ycord + 1 ,Board.HIGHLIGHT);
                               leftx = xcord -1;
                               lefty = ycord +1;
                             }



                          }

                          public void highlightright()
                           {
                             exist = b.getState(xcord, ycord);
                             if(exist == 1)
                             {
                               exist2 = b.getState(xcord+1, ycord -1);
                             }
                             if(exist == 2)
                             {
                               exist2 = b.getState(xcord+1, ycord +1);
                             }
                             if(exist == 1 && exist2 == 0)
                             {
                                b.setState(xcord+1,ycord -1, Board.HIGHLIGHT);
                                rightx = xcord+1;
                                righty = ycord -1;

                             }
                             else if(exist == 2 && exist2 == 0)
                             {
                               b.setState(xcord +1, ycord + 1 ,Board.HIGHLIGHT);
                               rightx = xcord+1;
                               righty=ycord +1;
                             }
                          }
                          public void removehighlight()
                          {
                            exist = b.getState(xcord,ycord);



                            b.setState(leftx,lefty,Board.EMPTY);
                            b.setState(rightx,righty,Board.EMPTY);

                          }


                          public void move()
                          {
                           exist = b.getState(xcord,ycord);
                           exist2 = b.getState(oldXvalue,oldYvalue);
                           if(exist == 5)
                           {
                             if(exist2 == 1)
                             {
                             b.setState(oldXvalue, oldYvalue, Board.EMPTY);
                             b.setState(xcord,ycord, Board.EMPTY);
                             b.setState(xcord,ycord, Board.RED);
                             }
                             else if(exist2 == 2)
                             {
                             b.setState(oldXvalue, oldYvalue, Board.EMPTY);
                             b.setState(xcord,ycord, Board.EMPTY);
                             b.setState(xcord,ycord, Board.BLUE);
                             }
                             /* 
                              * I think that there should be something here for the code to be cleared and then you can repeat it
                              */
                           }



                          }

                           public static void main(String [] args){ 

                             new Checkers();
                           }
                        }
```

Comment: Is there an error thrown?

Comment: Your checkerboard is off.  See this [website](http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/checkers-2.html) for the correct board and piece placement.  You need to use the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for a complicated game like checkers.  Create a CheckerPiece class that just has the fields and methods of a checker piece.  Create a Board class that just draws a checkerboard.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Checkers GUI.

I have not implemented moves yet, although I have started to code the MouseListener.  Here is what the Checkers GUI looks like.

[image: Checkers GUI]

I used a [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) to code this GUI.  I wrote 4 model classes, 3 view classes, and 5 controller classes.

When I code a Swing GUI, here's how I implement the MVC pattern:

1. The view may get information from the model.
2. The view may not update the model.
3. The controller will update the model, and repaint the view.

I don't have a single controller class.  So far, I have 5 controller classes.

Here's the main class, Checkers.

```
package com.ggl.checkers;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.checkers.model.CheckersModel;
import com.ggl.checkers.view.CheckersFrame;

public class Checkers implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Checkers());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new CheckersFrame(new CheckersModel());
    }
}
```

Short and effective.  This 19 line Java class does 3 things.

1. Puts the Swing GUI on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT) by calling the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.
2. Instantiates the CheckersModel class.
3. Instantiates the CheckersFrame class.

Next, let's look at the model classes.  This is the CheckersModel class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.ggl.checkers.model.CheckerPiece.PieceType;

public class CheckersModel {

    private Color boardEdgeColor;
    private Color lightSquareColor;
    private Color darkSquareColor;
    private Color lightPieceColor;
    private Color darkPieceColor;

    private GameParameters gameParameters;

    private List<CheckerPiece> pieces;
    private List<CheckerSquare> board;
    private List<GameParameters> parameters;


    public CheckersModel() {
        this.parameters = new ArrayList<GameParameters>();
        setGameParameters();

        this.boardEdgeColor = Color.ORANGE;
        this.lightSquareColor = Color.WHITE;
        this.darkSquareColor = Color.GRAY;
        this.lightPieceColor = Color.RED;
        this.darkPieceColor = Color.BLACK;

        this.board = new ArrayList<CheckerSquare>();
        setBoard();

        this.pieces = new ArrayList<CheckerPiece>();
        setPieces();
    }

    public void setGameParameters() {
        this.gameParameters = new GameParameters(
                "American Checkers", 8, 12, true, false);
        gameParameters.setSelected(true);
        parameters.add(gameParameters);

        GameParameters gp = new GameParameters(
                "Canadian Checkers", 12, 30, true, true);
        parameters.add(gp);

        gp = new GameParameters(
                "International Checkers", 10, 20, true, true);
        parameters.add(gp);
    }

    public void setGameParameters(GameParameters gameParameters) {
        this.gameParameters = gameParameters;
    }

    public void setBoard() {
        this.board.clear();
        Color color1 = getLightSquareColor();
        Color color2 = getDarkSquareColor();
        if (!gameParameters.isLightSquareOnRight()) {
            color1 = getDarkSquareColor();
            color2 = getLightSquareColor();
        }

        int squareWidth = gameParameters.getSquareWidth();
        int squaresPerSide = gameParameters.getSquaresPerSide();
        int margin = squareWidth / 2;

        int x = margin;
        int y = margin;

        for (int i = 0; i < squaresPerSide; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < squaresPerSide; j++) {
                Color color = null;

                if (getGameParameters().isLightSquareOnRight()) {
                    if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
                        color = color1;
                    } else {
                        color = color2;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
                        color = color2;
                    } else {
                        color = color1;
                    }
                }

                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, squareWidth, squareWidth);
                Point p = new Point(i, j);

                CheckerSquare cs = new CheckerSquare(color, p, r);
                board.add(cs);

                x += squareWidth;
            }

            y += squareWidth;
            x = margin;
        }
    }

    public void setPieces() {
        this.pieces.clear();

        int squaresPerSide = getGameParameters().getSquaresPerSide();
        Color topColor = getDarkPieceColor();
        Color bottomColor = getLightPieceColor();
        if (!getGameParameters().isLightMovesFirst()) {
            topColor = getLightPieceColor();
            bottomColor = getDarkPieceColor();
        }

        int rows = getGameParameters().getPiecesPerSide() * 2 / squaresPerSide;

        for (int i = 0; i < squaresPerSide; i++) {
            if (i < rows) {
                if (getGameParameters().isLightSquareOnRight()) {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        setPieceRow(topColor, i, 1);
                    } else {
                        setPieceRow(topColor, i, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        setPieceRow(topColor, i, 0);
                    } else {
                        setPieceRow(topColor, i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (i > (squaresPerSide - rows - 1)) {
                if (getGameParameters().isLightSquareOnRight()) {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        setPieceRow(bottomColor, i, 1);
                    } else {
                        setPieceRow(bottomColor, i, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        setPieceRow(bottomColor, i, 0);
                    } else {
                        setPieceRow(bottomColor, i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void resetPieceColor(Color previousColor, Color newColor) {
        for (CheckerPiece cp : pieces) {
            if (cp.getColor().equals(previousColor)) {
                cp.setColor(newColor);
            }
        }
    }

    public void resetSquareColor(Color previousColor, Color newColor) {
        for (CheckerSquare cs : board) {
            if (cs.getColor().equals(previousColor)) {
                cs.setColor(newColor);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setPieceRow(Color color, int row, int column) {
        int squaresPerSide = gameParameters.getSquaresPerSide();

        for (int j = column; j < squaresPerSide; j += 2) {
            CheckerPiece cp = new CheckerPiece(color, PieceType.Man);
            cp.setLocation(new Point(row, j));
            pieces.add(cp);
        }
    }

    public int getSquaresPerSide() {
        return gameParameters.getSquaresPerSide();
    }

    public Color getBoardEdgeColor() {
        return boardEdgeColor;
    }

    public void setBoardEdgeColor(Color boardEdgeColor) {
        this.boardEdgeColor = boardEdgeColor;
    }

    public Color getLightSquareColor() {
        return lightSquareColor;
    }

    public void setLightSquareColor(Color lightSquareColor) {
        this.lightSquareColor = lightSquareColor;
    }

    public Color getDarkSquareColor() {
        return darkSquareColor;
    }

    public void setDarkSquareColor(Color darkSquareColor) {
        this.darkSquareColor = darkSquareColor;
    }

    public Color getLightPieceColor() {
        return lightPieceColor;
    }

    public void setLightPieceColor(Color lightPieceColor) {
        this.lightPieceColor = lightPieceColor;
    }

    public Color getDarkPieceColor() {
        return darkPieceColor;
    }

    public void setDarkPieceColor(Color darkPieceColor) {
        this.darkPieceColor = darkPieceColor;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredBoardSize() {
        int squareWidth = gameParameters.getSquareWidth();
        int squaresPerSide = gameParameters.getSquaresPerSide();
        int width = squareWidth * (squaresPerSide + 1);
        return new Dimension(width, width);
    }

    public List<GameParameters> getGameParametersList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(parameters);
    }

    public GameParameters getGameParameters() {
        return gameParameters;
    }

    public CheckerPiece getPieceOnSquare(Point p) {
        for (CheckerPiece cp : pieces) {
            if (cp.isLocation(p)) {
                return cp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CheckerPiece getPieceOnSquare(int x, int y) {
        for (CheckerSquare cs : board) {
            if (cs.containsLocation(x, y)) {
                CheckerPiece cp = getPieceOnSquare(cs.getCoordinate());
                return cp;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int squareWidth = gameParameters.getSquareWidth();
        int squaresPerSide = gameParameters.getSquaresPerSide();
        int width = squareWidth * (squaresPerSide + 1);

        g.setColor(getBoardEdgeColor());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, width);

        for (CheckerSquare cs : board) {
            cs.draw(g);
            CheckerPiece cp = getPieceOnSquare(cs.getCoordinate());
            if (cp != null) {
                cp.draw(g, cs.getLocation(), squareWidth);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You'll see the the board squares, as well as the checker pieces, are kept in a list.  The board squares are kept in a list because I needed to know the pixel positions of each square.  As you'll see later, I put the pixel positions in a Rectangle.  This allows me to convert a mouse click to a square, and eventually to a checker piece.

The GameParameters class holds the parameters for a particular checkers game.  Right now, I have American checkers, Canadian checkers, and International checkers.  You can see on the GUI image that the different checker games have different parameters.

Next, let's look at the GameParameters class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.model;

public class GameParameters {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private boolean lightSquareOnRight;
    private boolean lightMovesFirst;

    private int piecesPerSide;
    private int squaresPerSide;
    private int squareWidth;

    private String gameName;

    public GameParameters(String gameName, int squaresPerSide,
            int piecesPerSide, boolean lightSquareOnRight,
            boolean lightMovesFirst) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.squaresPerSide = squaresPerSide;
        this.piecesPerSide = piecesPerSide;
        this.lightSquareOnRight = lightSquareOnRight;
        this.lightMovesFirst = lightMovesFirst;
        this.squareWidth = 500 / squaresPerSide;
        this.isSelected = false;
    }

    public boolean isLightSquareOnRight() {
        return lightSquareOnRight;
    }

    public boolean isLightMovesFirst() {
        return lightMovesFirst;
    }

    public int getPiecesPerSide() {
        return piecesPerSide;
    }

    public int getSquaresPerSide() {
        return squaresPerSide;
    }

    public int getSquareWidth() {
        return squareWidth;
    }

    public String getGameName() {
        return gameName;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return gameName;
    }
}
```

This class holds the game parameters that make each checkers variation unique.

Next, let's look at the CheckerSquare class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CheckerSquare {

    private Color color;

    private Point coordinate;

    private Rectangle location;

    public CheckerSquare(Color color, Point coordinate, Rectangle location) {
        this.color = color;
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Point getCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }

    public Rectangle getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public boolean containsLocation(int x, int y) {
        return location.contains(x, y);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(location.x, location.y, location.width, location.height);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, each square is defined by a Rectangle that let's us know where the square is located.  This allows a mouse click to be converted to a square coordinate, and eventually, a piece coordinate.

Finally, we'll look at the CheckerPiece class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CheckerPiece {

    private Color color;

    private PieceType pieceType;

    private Point location;

    public CheckerPiece(Color color, PieceType pieceType) {
        this.color = color;
        this.pieceType = pieceType;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public boolean isLocation(Point location) {
        return ((this.location.x == location.x) 
                && (this.location.y == location.y));
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public PieceType getPieceType() {
        return pieceType;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g, Rectangle r, int width) {
        drawCircle(g, getCenter(r), width * 4 / 10);
    }

    private Point getCenter(Rectangle r) {
        int x = r.x + r.width / 2;
        int y = r.y + r.height / 2;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    private void drawCircle(Graphics g, Point center, int radius) {
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 
                radius + radius, radius + radius);
    }

    public enum PieceType {
        Man, King
    }

}
```

Next, we'll look at the view classes.  First, we'll look at the CheckersFrame class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.view;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.checkers.controller.MoveMouseListener;
import com.ggl.checkers.model.CheckersModel;
import com.ggl.checkers.model.GameParameters;

public class CheckersFrame {

    private BoardPanel boardPanel;

    private CheckersModel model;

    private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    public CheckersFrame(CheckersModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Checkers");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        boardPanel = new BoardPanel(model);
        boardPanel.addMouseListener(new MoveMouseListener(model));

        controlPanel = new ControlPanel(this, model);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        mainPanel.add(boardPanel);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.add(controlPanel.getPanel());
        mainPanel.add(rightPanel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void updateControlPanelPartControl(GameParameters item) {
        controlPanel.updatePartControl(item);
    }

    public void repaintBoardPanel() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The createPartControl method is boilerplate for creating a JFrame.  We use a JFrame.  You should only extend a Swing component or any other Java class when you're going to override a method.

Next, let's look at the BoardPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.checkers.view;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.checkers.model.CheckersModel;

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7726343503195297509L;

    private CheckersModel model;

    public BoardPanel(CheckersModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.setPreferredSize(model.getPreferredBoardSize());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        model.draw(g);
    }

}
```

This class calls the drawing code in the model, which draws the checker board and the checker pieces.

An answer is limited to 30,000 characters.  I can continue this discussion in another answer if someone thinks it's worthwhile.  I still have 1 view class and 5 controller classes to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea when you get your errors so its hard to say anything without knowing what the actual error is.

But I would say your highlighting code could remove any red blue checker piece location information, you don't check if there is information there already. Your highlight method has a couple of ifs and and an if else statement. The if's will all be checked as well as the if else block.

But I could he wrong on this assumption because its hard to know what all your == code means as you don't use constants.

Comment: Someone write it and show what you mean. I tried the variable and it was giving me errors. This is just making me pull out my hair.